# Maven-install Unsupported Class Version Error

Tags: java, maven, version

I have cloned a Maven repository which I wish to use and build on my machine. I used to be able to build this particular project, but now when I choose maven install, it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Which is really strange. I know that this maven project uses java 6, and it shows so in the pom.xml, but my machine already has java 6 installed. In fact, the project says it's using it. What's going on?

Comment: [51.0 is actually Java 7](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195).

Comment: Yes and that's weird because pom.xml AND eclipse project both say they want to use java 6

Comment: What do you mean by "pom.xml want to use Java 6"?

Comment: Like, in the pom.xml, where you configure maven compiler plugin, you can change what version of java to build with.

Comment: Also, I think I am using maven 3.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your project uses Java 6, Maven version 3.3.3 (latest at this time) needs Java 7.

Either use Maven 3.2.5 (that uses Java 6) or install Java 7.

Reference:

https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html

Comment: I think that is my problem. Thanks